# I'm trying to convert json to a c# object

Tags: c#, .net, json

I've tried several methods for doing this but I can't seem to succeed.

I wrote a piece of code that creates an http get request. this works fine. It gets a json repsonse.

the response looks like this :

```
    [
    {
        "date": "2014-12-08",
        "activityTimeSeries": [
            {
                "timezone": "Europe/Helsinki",
                "start_time": "2014-12-07T22:00:00Z",
                "steps": {
                    "link": "/api/users/nxrogcjqjfwokltr/data/unify_data/54880e2933ae997aa32c2236"
                },
                "source": "fitbit"
            }
        ],
        "gpx": [],
        "exercise": [],
        "activity": [
            {
                "distance": 4520,
                "caloriesTotal": 2451,
                "caloriesBMR": 1866,
                "source": "fitbit",
                "steps": 5581,
                "caloriesActive": 585
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2014-12-09",
        "activityTimeSeries": [
            {
                "timezone": "Europe/Helsinki",
                "start_time": "2014-12-08T22:00:00Z",
                "steps": {
                    "link": "/api/users/nxrogcjqjfwokltr/data/unify_data/54880c0d33ae997aa32c2219"
                },
                "source": "fitbit"
            }
        ],
        "gpx": [],
        "exercise": [],
        "activity": [
            {
                "distance": 3960,
                "caloriesTotal": 2414,
                "caloriesBMR": 1866,
                "source": "fitbit",
                "steps": 4896,
                "caloriesActive": 548
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I get this to work ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is solved by a simple search of the net.

Comment: Have you JSON stringified your object so that it could be deserialized by C#?

Comment: Your piece of code is somehow invisible.

Comment: When you need to deserialize JSON, it's usually best to **1)** Ensure you have valid JSON by running it through [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) **2)** Create an object model to represent the response (Tools such as [Json2CSharp](http://json2csharp.com/) can assist with this, though their output isn't always perfect), **3)** pick your deserialization library - there's one built into .NET, or you can use popular libraries such as [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) to do it. You need to follow these steps, then if you run into specific problems you can create a question. Show effort!

Comment: Hi , and thanks for the replies. @mason thanks for the tips, I did exactly as you said and managed to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. My recommendation would be to simply use a JSON library, unless you have a particular reason not to.

Json.NET is what I use. It's fairly straightforward, especially if you have any experience with JSON in Java.

http://james.newtonking.com/json

https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json

Using that library, you'll need to create a container class, using, I believe, the same variable names as the JSON entry titles.

```
class JsonContainer
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; };
    public string[] activityTimeSeries { get; set; };
    etc.
}
```

When you have a Model object you can deserialise to, then it's simply a matter of calling something along the lines of

```
JsonContainer jc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonContainer>(your json as a string here);
```

Without more information, like what you actually did, I'm not sure how much help you'll be able to get.

Comment: Alrighty, I'll add a code sample to my question when I get some time later on. Cheers for the headsup.

Answer (score -1):

Just use NewtonsoftJson

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/

and do this

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourClass>(responseString);
```